# Pushing and popping the same register via stack

Tags: assembly, stack, embedded, cpu-registers, msp430

I think I understand the Push/Pop concept onto/from stack in MSP430, but not sure what happens in this situation:

```
mov #8, R10
push R10
call #myfunc
```

Then inside the subroutine 'myfunc':

```
push R10
push R11
push R12

..... do some ops with R10
pop R10
pop R11
pop R12
ret
```

What happens when we push again R10 and pop before 'ret' and use it in that way? R5 is not used again in 'main'.

I am still new to this - thank you

Comment: Check if there's a common ABI or calling convention for how C code should behave when using MSP430. Should caller or callee do the stacking, and which registers are commonly used etc. That documentation should be found among C compiler docs. Then try to always follow that calling convention standard when writing assembler, so that you can mix C and asm seamlessly.

Comment: Why are you mentioning R5? And are you sure that the function is using R10 without loading it from memory?

Answer (score 0):

If you push same register twice, the value will exist in two addresses in the stack. There is no point in doing it twice.

You should also keep in mind that the amount of push and pop instructions should match to prevent useless data piling up in the stack. You can remove "push R10" before the call since you already do it after the call.

EDIT: You should also pull the registers in the opposite order you pushed them to make sure things end up in their respective registers

Comment: The amount of push and pop instructions should match in a function mainly because you could pop a invalid address in the program counter when executing ret.